Ubuntu 24.04 Desktop problem on old hardware
Can I run Ubuntu 24.04 Desktop on this old hardware?
The system boots OK, but selecting a menu within GNOME Files (Nautilus 46.2) produces a dropdown window which flickers then disappears completely and leaves a small illegible image beside the (absent) dropdown.
The hardware is OK with Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.
  Processor: Core-2 Quad Q8400
  RAM: 4GB
  Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 9400 GT
  System: Ubuntu 24.04
  Arch: x86-64
  Kernel: 68.0.38-generic
  DE: Ubuntu GNOME (Wayland) - GDM3
unreadable sub-image beside pull-down:


This question is similar to: Ubuntu 24.04 screen glitches on gnome apps after install. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I just reinstalled Ubuntu 24.04 and did the following actions. This fixed the bug
In a terminal run :
sudo nano /etc/environment

to edit the file, then, add :
GSK_RENDERER=gl 

to the end of the file.

ctrl+x to save and confirm with Y or O.

Finally logout and reopen your session.
It seems that adding this option fixes a lot of bugs on old graphics cards
